# javascript & api calls: how to get value returned from an api call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I define code like this

```
var price;
$.getJSON('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05', function( data ) {
  price = data.bpi;
});
```

then I can get price from `console`;

However, if I define code like this

```
var price;
$.getJSON('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05', function( data ) {
  price = data.bpi;
});
console.log(price);
```

the `price` can still be accessed from console, but `console.log` returns `undefine`.

---

My question is that how can I get the `price` returned from `data.api`, so I can latter use the data to do some further calculation, such as

```
var x = Object.keys(price);
var y = Object.values(price);
// some plot using x, y, and some calculations
```

Comment: Your console.log is happening before the function returns. That's the asynchronous nature of how api calls are handled. So, you need to put any code that relies on the returned data inside the function where you currently have `price=data.bpi`

Comment: Consume the data in the callback

Answer (score 0):

The get method is asynchronous meaning that the code execution proceeds to the statement after the get block without waiting for it. Once the get call completes, the code inside the get block is executed with the result returned. Thus, the console log statement is executed even before the call has finished and is undefined.

If you want to process the data returned, all calculations have to be done inside the callback method of the get() function.

```
  $.getJSON('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05', function( data ) {
  price = data.bpi;
  var x = Object.keys(price);
  var y = Object.values(price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [javascript promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are what you're looking for.

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-09-05';
  $.getJSON(url, data => {
    resolve(data);
  });
});

//and then later

promise.then(data => {
  console.log(data.bpi);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

`price = data.bpi;` can't run right away but your code continues to execute so `console.log(price);` runs before `price = data.bpi;`.

Also when you want to use the data later you might have to wait for it to be available. That's what the promise is doing.